# How to read an image from iOS project to set into html embed code in iOS project

Tags: html, ios

I want to read image from my project and want to set to  tag.
This is what i am doing.

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audioIconHtml" ofType:@"jpeg"];
[outdata appendFormat:@"<a href = \"%@\"><img src=\"%@\"  width = \"200\" height = \"200\"></a><br>",fname,tileDirectory];
```

but it show a blank bordered area with size but no image.

Comment: Have you verified that `tileDirectory` is non-nil?

Comment: yes.. it gives me full path of the image "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/E3A2F22A-1CFB-4F90-BB77-54F38C9153A2/WiFiTransfer.app/audioIconHtml.jpeg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Looks like you are trying to load an image in `UIWebView`.

If that is the case then you should check the baseURL of the `UIWebView` you are setting.

you should try your code like following,

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audioIconHtml" ofType:@"jpeg"];
[outdata appendFormat:@"<a href = \"%@\"><img src=\"%@\"  width = \"200\" height = \"200\"></a><br>",fname,tileDirectory];

[webView loadHTMLString:outdata baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@/",[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]]]];
```

Comment: No, i don't want to load this html string in UIWebView. The app will create a web page that will be load in a browser on pc or any other device.

Comment: question is not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: your answer is correct if we show the html string in webview, but the case is that, the iphone app will work like a server and it will generate a url on same network, where other user on mac or pc, will use that link in browser. The html page will be displayed with few image button, we need to show images on button. We need to set image on html button, thats why we are using <img src="">, like that.